# Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq is adding backslash to all space characters in search query

Tags: solr, content-search, graphql

Whenever I query using the `Like` query the Sitecore generated Solr query escapes the space characters. Here is an example:

```
queryable = queryable.Where(result =>
                    result["displayName"].Like(keywordArg).Boost(2.0f) ||
                    result.Name.Like(keywordArg).Boost(2.0f) ||
                    result.Content.Like(keywordArg)
                );
```

Generates:

```
(displayname_t:(Test\ Query\ Test~0.5))^2 OR (_name:(Test\ Query\ Test~0.5))^2 OR _content:(Test\ Query\ Test~0.5)
```

I am using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq 10.1.0.

My expectation would be that it does not add a backslash to the generated query.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does it have to do with the type of analyzer used?

Comment: I am not overriding any of the default Solr Analyzers. I am also not sure when those analyzers would be applied? I took the generated query from the Solr logs. I thought the Sitecore ContentSearch library would generate the query and then Solr would run its analyzers internally. I am not an expert with this particular pipeline though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to find the direct cause of this issue but I have found a possible solution.

When using the `Like` function with the `slop` parameter `Like<T>(this T value, string phraseComparison, int slop)`, it formats the query correctly without the backslashes. From the logs: `_content:("Test query Test test"~1)`

I believe the phrase query is closer to what I am hoping to achieve so this should be OK.